# Proving a basis of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm struggling with the following Question:

Let $V$ be a vector space and $B=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$.

Prove that $B$ is a basis of $V$ if and only if  $\forall i$ s.t $1\leq i \leq n$:

$V=Span(v_i)\oplus Span(\{v_j |j\neq i\})$

---

In one direction it's pretty obvious (when I assume $B$ is a basis of $V$).

In the other direction, I'm able to show that $B$ spans $V$ but I'm not sure how to show that $B$ is also linearly independent. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that, for each $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $V=\operatorname{span}(v_i)\bigoplus\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{v_j\mid j\ne i\}\bigr)$. You want to prove that $B$ is a basis of $V$. Since $V=\operatorname{span}(v_1)\bigoplus\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{v_j\mid j>1\}\bigr)$, $B$ spans $V$. All that remains to be proved is that $B$ is linearly independent. Suppose otherwise. Then, for some $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $v_i$ is a linear combination of the $v_j$'s (with $j\ne i$). But then $v_i$ belongs to $\operatorname{span}(v_i)$ and also to $\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{v_j\mid j\ne i\}\bigr)$. But then $\operatorname{span}(v_i)$ and $\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{v_j\mid j\ne i\}\bigr)$ do not form a direct sum.